# Get the right number in the String

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to pick the integer value `30`in this string which hast the form \s\d\d\s. I have tried the code below but I am getting the Minute value 30 at the end of the line too but I want just to get the value `30` which has this form `\s\d\d\s`. How can I fix that?

I appreciate any help.

**Line before doing m.group(); in this line are two 30 number**

```
wall street 4 06:28 07:29 07:59 08:29 08:59 30 19:59 20:29 21:04 22:04 23:04 00:04 00:30
```

**Line after:**

```
wall street 4 06:28 07:29 07:59 08:29 08:59 19:59 20:29 21:04 22:04 23:04 00:04 00:
```

**Result should Looks like**

```
wall street 4 06:28 07:29 07:59 08:29 08:59 19:59 20:29 21:04 22:04 23:04 00:04 00:30
```

**my Code:**

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\d\\s)\\d{2}(?=\\s\\d)");

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
    while (m.find()) {
        value = Integer.parseInt(m.group().trim());

        line = line.replace(m.group(), " ").replaceAll(" +", " ");


    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just use pattern "(\\s\\d\\d\\s)" or "(\\s\\d+\\s)"?

Comment: I dont want get the number `14` if I have this case `wall street 14` .

Comment: Sorry cant understand what do you want. Can you explain what does it mean value "30"

Comment: @paul_di: in the line there is two 30 number once has this form ` 30 ` also surrounded with space and the other one `00:30` at the end of the line. I want to get the number with has this form `integer+space+integer+integer+space+intger`. I dont want to get the `14` in this case `wall street 14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it happening?

Your pattern is OK and matching `30` as required.. but in the `while` loop.. you are replacing `m.group()` (which is now `30`) with `" "`.. hence all the instances where you have `30` will be replaced..

> How to fix?

You can replace the pattern directly.. i.e:

```
line = line.replaceAll("(?<=\\d\\s)\\d{2}(?=\\s\\d)", "").replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

Code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\d\\s)\\d{2}(?=\\s\\d)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    value = Integer.parseInt(m.group().trim());
}
line = line.replaceAll("(?<=\\d\\s)\\d{2}(?=\\s\\d)", "").replaceAll(" +", " ");
System.out.println(line);
```

See [Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/U6RVVb)

Comment: But I want to store this value `30` in variable since I need it later.

Comment: When I replace later I am getting this error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found` otherwise inside the Loop it works now for me?

Answer (score 3):

You can just do:

```
line = line.replaceAll("(?<=\\d\\s)\\d{2}\\s*(?=\\d)", "");
```

to get your output.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT8lE0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a independently calling `line.replace(m.group(), " ").replaceAll(" +", " ");` you can use the [matcher's replace functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29).

Like this:

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/o7amli)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String line = "wall street 4 06:28 07:29 07:59 08:29 08:59 30 19:59 20:29 21:04 22:04 23:04 00:04 00:30";
        System.out.println( "Input:  " + line );
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\s+\\d{2}(?=\\s)");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
        while (m.find()) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(m.group().trim());
            line = m.replaceFirst("");
            System.out.println( "Output: " + line );
        }    
    }
}
```